# How to assign outer var inside of an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to assign a value to a variable that is defined outside of an arrow function like this:

```
    let leftPanel: PerspectivePanel;
    let rightPanel: PerspectivePanel;

    let temp = L.withFlex(1, L.box(direction, [
      L.withFlex(
          1,
          element => {
            element.className = 'gllayoutcell noselect';
            leftPanel = new PerspectivePanel(display, element, perspectiveViewerState);
            this.registerDisposer(leftPanel);
          }),
      L.withFlex(
          1,
          element => {
            element.className = 'gllayoutcell noselect';
            rightPanel = new PerspectivePanel(display, element, perspectiveViewerState2);
            this.registerDisposer(rightPanel);
          }),
    ]))(rootElement);

    leftPanel.otherRenderedDataPanel = rightPanel;
    rightPanel.otherRenderedDataPanel = leftPanel;
```

But the compiler gives me errors that the variable is being used before being defined. How can I make the variable inside there visible to the outside?

EDIT: What I do not understand how it can be that the arrow function get's called after the two assignments below it. Because clearly it is getting called before them with element being rootElement.

Comment: I assume it's saying that for the `leftPanel.otherRenderedDataPanel = ...` assignment line and the one below?

Comment: Please can you supply a minimal working example. I would have to define a lot of things in your example in order to even get it to where the error is visible... but I suspect you could create the error without all of your missing types.

Comment: Yes the leftPanel.otherRenderedDataPanel line.gives the error.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is complaining because both `leftPanel` and `rightPanel` may not have been assigned yet. That's because they are first assigned in one of your arrow functions, for which it is unknown at compile time when they are going to be called.

I'm assuming you use `strictNullChecks: true`. In that case, you can work around this issue by explicitly stating that each of the two variables can be `undefined` and then using type assertion:

```
let leftPanel: PerspectivePanel | undefined;
let rightPanel: PerspectivePanel | undefined;

...

leftPanel!.otherRenderedDataPanel = rightPanel!;
rightPanel!.otherRenderedDataPanel = leftPanel!;
```

Comment: Good advice, but then I get `Type 'RenderedDataPanel | undefined' is not assignable to type 'RenderedDataPanel'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'RenderedDataPanel'`.

Comment: Right, that's why you need non-null assertions (the ! following an identifier).

Comment: I had that it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by defining reft and right Panel as class properties and inside of the arrow function I could do `this.rightPanel.otherPanel = leftPanel`. I still don't know why the other approach did not work, but this was a workaround that for me.